# Filtering for slope using kernel size in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, spatial-analyst, filter

I have problem in smoothing the slope derived from digital elevation model. I want to do filter for the slope <5 degree in 7 X 7 kernel size, 5-20 degree in 5X5 kernel and >20 degree slope in 3X3 kernel size. But I am not able to put these kernel size condition in filter tools in ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.

Comment: ArcGIS slope calculations are all computed within 3x3 neighborhoods, so what exactly is this "kernel" supposed to be doing for you?